# MVC3 Paging - only load the rows in the current page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a WebGrid like control that would display a gallery (a list of images) that could have many pages. I don't want to load all the rows at the same time that's why I'm unable to use WebGrid and PagedList.

Is there any other alternative to this, taking only a portion of the rows (list.skip(x).take(y))?

Thanks,
czetsuya

Answer (score 0):

See [this post in ASP.Net forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1724484.aspx/1?ASP%20NET%20MVC%203%20Paging%20Question)

This method uses row wise results from database. This result is fetched according to the pagenumber.